# How can I get a reference to the main application MIDlet object when running Codename one application on Nokia s40 device?

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone, nokia-s40

I'm trying to integrate the Nokia in app purchase for s40 and Asha library to my application. The NPayManager constructor needs a reference to the running MIDlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIDlet is passed in the init method of your main class.

```
public void init(Object context)
```

Note that you can only downcast to MIDlet in the j2me Native Interface section.Read more about native interface here - http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html